# How do I sort this in React? I'm doing something wrong here, probably syntactically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to sort a list of items by 'likes' in React. I'm having a lot of difficulty with this task. The program works when the list is in the default sort, but when I sort by 'likes,' I start throwing errors. I've tried a million things to no avail. It may have to do with datatypes (Array vs Object) or possibly the spread operator, but your guess is as good as mine. I'm currently getting a

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

but I feel like this is not the main problem here, but rather a resulting error. Here's the source:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { List } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import ItemsListItem from './ItemsListItem';

class ItemsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {sorted: false}
  }

  compareItems() {
    return function (a, b) {
      if (a.likes < b.likes) return -1;
      if (a.likes > b.likes) return 1;
      return 0;
    };
  }

  sortList(list = this.props){
    if (!this.state.sorted){

//problem area
      let listCopy = [...list];
      listCopy.sort(this.compareItems())
//problem area

      return listCopy;
    }else{
      debugger
      return list
    }
  }

  sortStatus() {
      this.setState({sorted: !this.state.sorted});
  }

  render(){
    const { items } = this.sortList(this.props)
    return (
      <div>
        <List className="center">
          {items.map((item, i) =>
              <ItemsListItem item={item} key={i}/>
            )}
        </List>
        <button className="ui red button" onClick={() => this.sortStatus()}>
          Sort
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ItemsList;
```

... and a sample item:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "name":"Hamburger",
      "category":"Entrees",
      "created_at":"2018-09-20T02:44:04.030Z",
      "updated_at":"2018-10-05T04:03:13.458Z",
      "likes":4,
      "ingredients":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"Bun",
            "item_id":1,
            "created_at":"2018-09-20T02:44:04.070Z",
            "updated_at":"2018-09-20T02:44:04.070Z"
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"Beef Patty",
            "item_id":1,
            "created_at":"2018-09-20T02:44:04.088Z",
            "updated_at":"2018-09-20T02:44:04.088Z"
         },
         {  
            "id":3,
            "name":"Lettuce",
            "item_id":1,
            "created_at":"2018-09-20T02:44:04.106Z",
            "updated_at":"2018-09-20T02:44:04.106Z"
         },
         {  
            "id":4,
            "name":"Tomato",
            "item_id":1,
            "created_at":"2018-09-20T02:44:04.125Z",
            "updated_at":"2018-09-20T02:44:04.125Z"
         },
         {  
            "id":5,
            "name":"Onion",
            "item_id":1,
            "created_at":"2018-09-20T02:44:04.143Z",
            "updated_at":"2018-09-20T02:44:04.143Z"
         }
      ]
   },
...
]
```

Edit: Solution:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { List } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import ItemsListItem from './ItemsListItem';

class ItemsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {sorted: false}
  }

  compareItems() {
    return function (a, b) {
      if (a.likes < b.likes) return -1;
      if (a.likes > b.likes) return 1;
      return 0;
    };
  }

  sortList(list) {
    if (!this.state.sorted){
      let listCopy = [...list];
      listCopy.sort(this.compareItems())
      return listCopy;
    }else{
      return list
    }
  }

  sortStatus() {
      this.setState({sorted: !this.state.sorted});
  }

  render(){
    const { items } = this.props
    let itemsUsable = this.sortList(items)
    return (
      <div>
        <List className="center">
          {itemsUsable.map((item, i) =>
              <ItemsListItem item={item} key={i}/>
            )}
        </List>
        <button className="ui red button" onClick={() => this.sortStatus()}>
          Sort
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ItemsList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what to change:

```
sortList(list = this.props){
  if (!this.state.sorted){
```

change to:

```
sortList() {
  const { list } = this.props
  if (!this.state.sorted){
```

And then when you're calling the `sortList` function, don't pass in parameters, and I think you need to remove `{}` from around your `items` variable - not sure why it's there?:

```
const { items } = this.sortList(this.props)
```

change to:

```
const items = this.sortList()
```

Explanation: First, if you're calling a function that belongs to an instance of an object, then there's no need to pass properties of that object into that function as parameters. Just get them directly from within the function (ie, from within your `sortList` function in this case), and don't have any parameters.

Second, destructuring parameters from `this.props`, as you try to do in `sortList(list = this.props){`, is not valid syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Any advice on this new error? The line in question is: 

      let listCopy = [...list];
 ... and the error in question is... 
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

_toConsumableArray

Comment: hmm not off the top of my head. Add some logging inside the `sortList` function. What does `console.log(list)` show it to be? What does `console.log(this.props)` show it to be?

Comment: It's throwing a blank array for 'this.props'. Why it's not reading the props, I have no idea.

Comment: Add a `console.log(this.props)` in your `render(){` function. Make sure props holds what you expect there first, then move on.

Comment: Blank array there too, what gives?

Comment: Okay, i got it. Thanks for leading the way. Post updated with solution if you're curious.